# No Route Matches when passing perameter Rails 3

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to get a route so that I pass a string through that I can use in the controller to query the database.

```
 controller:
 def sales
@sales= Micropost.where(:sale_name => params[:sale])
@sales = Sale.sales
 end

View:
<%= link_to('See all', :controller =>"microposts", :action => "sales", :sale => sales_item.sale_name) %>

Routes.rb
match '/sales/:sale', :to => 'microposts#sales'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to `match 'microposts/sales' => 'microposts#sales'` and you can pass the parameters to that action.

[You can also make it a named route](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes), which will look something like, `match 'sales' => 'microposts#sales', :as => :sales`. With this, you'll get `sales_url` and `sales_path`. You can use then as, for eg., `sales_path(:sale => sales_item.sale_name)`.

Hope this helps.